# (MATLAB) How can I move the origin of plotted points?

Tags: matlab, plot

I wasn't sure how to word this question so please link me to any answer if this has been asked before.

Let's say I have a graph with points making a line that starts at (5, 10) and goes to (10,10), but I want to move the points so that the first point starts at (0, 10) up to (5, 10). How do I go about doing this? Or what is this called so I can search on my own? I still want the points to be the same distances apart relative to each other but with one of the points at a specific location that I specify.

Comment: Find the minimum of coordinates, `5` and subtract it from all the coordinates, which will give you `(0,5) and (5,5)` and is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply take all of your points, and subtract or add them by a certain amount to move the origin.  As such, because you want to move your line such that the horizontal component is shifted to the left by 5, you can just subtract every `x` co-ordinate by 5.

As such, assuming your co-ordinates are in `x` and `y`, just do:

```
final_x = x - 5;
final_y = y;
```

Then go ahead and plot these values:

```
plot(final_x, final_y);
```

In general, if you want to move your points by a prescribed amount, do this:

```
final_x = x + x_shift;
final_y = y + y_shift;
```

`x_shift` and `y_shift` would be the amount of movement you want the `x` and `y` co-ordinates to move.  In this case, you want to move everything to the left by 5, and so `x_shift = -5` and `y_shift = 0`.  If you want to move everything such that the origin is located at `(0,0)`, you would make `x_shift` and `y_shift` to be the minimum of the `x` and `y` values, or:

```
x_shift = min(x);
y_shift = min(y);
```

Using this will ensure that all of your points are with respect to `(0,0)`.

Comment: Oh jeeze, duh. Thank you so much!

Comment: @user2444127 - If you can and if I helped you, accept my answer when you're able to do so!  I know I replied very quickly, and there's a wait time... so whenever you get to it :)  Thanks!